# Eclipse(Ubuntu) doesnt show one plus one device even if USB debugging is turned on

Tags: android, eclipse, oneplusone

I have tried installing my application into the oneplus one device but the eclipse(Ubuntu) doesn't recognize the device. How can this problem be solved? I have tried the link http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html , but there is no rule for OnePlusOne devices. Please Help!

Comment: DId you install oneplus device's usb driver to computer?

Comment: This is sometimes a priviledges error. Try `sudo adb kill-server` and then `sudo adb start-server`.

Comment: @SardorDushamov I couln't find the usb driver for Ubuntu. Where can I get the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think no need for driver in linux try this on oneplus one

Settings->Developer Options-->turn on Android Debugging. Settings-->Storage-->menu on the upper right corner-->USB computer connection-->check box MTP/PTP

Answer (score 1):

Install mtpfs from your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Get idVendor and idProduct of your mobile phone by connecting it to your system

```
mtp-detect | grep idVendor
mtp-detect | grep idProduct
```

Insert the follwing text to your 69-libmtp.rules file located at /lib/udev/rules.d replacing idVendor_got_above and idProduct_got_above

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="idVendor_got_above", ATTR{idProduct}=="idProduct_got_above", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1", TAG+="uaccess"
```